# How can I restore deleted permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, amazon-rds

We created a database and spent time loading the data. We might have accidentally changed some permissions, and now we are not longer able to access that database from the owner account (or any other). (We are both wading through the mud here)

Is there any way to restore the revoked permissions so we can access our data, or do we need to start all over?

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's all in the docs:

> You can reset the assigned permissions for your DB instance by
>   resetting the master password. For example, if you lock yourself out
>   of the db_owner role on your SQL Server database, you can reset the
>   db_owner role password by modifying the DB instance master password.
>   By changing the DB instance password, you can regain access to the DB
>   instance, access databases using the modified password for the
>   db_owner, and restore privileges for the db_owner role that may have
>   been accidentally revoked. You can change the DB instance password by
>   using the Amazon RDS console, the AWS CLI command modify-db-instance,
>   or by using the ModifyDBInstance action. For more information about
>   modifying a SQL Server DB instance, see Modifying a DB Instance
>   Running the Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.ResetPassword